# Degree of Line bundle and Intersection

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, intersection-theory

Let $(\Sigma,g)$ be a closed Riemann surface with metric $g$. 
For any holomorphic line bundle $L\to \Sigma$, given a metric we have its curtature  in terms of Chern connection $A$.

It is well-known that $\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_\Sigma F_A=\deg(L)$ is called the degree of Line bundle and $(\Sigma,g)$ induces a canonical orientation(as pointed by Yuan). $\frac{i}{2\pi}  F_A\in  H^2(\Sigma,\mathbb Z)$, the pairing with $[\Sigma]\in H_2(\Sigma,\mathbb Z)$ equals to $\deg(L)$.

Consider an examples:  $\Sigma$ stays some oriented closed $4$-dimensional manfiold $M$, $L$ denotes the normal bundle.

**Q**
 If we reverse the orientation of  $M$, the intersection number will change, hence the degree will change. By the relation, $\deg(L)=[\Sigma]^2$, this intersection numner should be indepedent on the choice of orientation.

Of course somewhere must go wrong, could anyone give a help.

Comment: Complex manifolds have a unique orientation consistent with the complex structure.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, could you point out where goes wrong for the example(intersection number).